# http2 ingress ssl-passthrough, curl works, chrome goes banana's

Tags: google-chrome, kubernetes

This works perfect for curl and chrome

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: example
            servicePort: 443
```

until you create a webpage where you are connecting to that service and using img call's (tiles) from another service on the same kube using the same ssl certificate. Then chrome wants to recycle the http2 connection resulting in requests getting send to the wrong pod. Note that curl keeps working for both services because it doesn't try to recycle the previous curl command http2 connection. Is there a workaround for this, other than running two different kube clusters so chrome doesn't recycle the http2 connection?